# @Valid for long data type is not working for mandatory check

Tags: spring-boot

I have the below input class and when i trigger the api without 'interactionId' param in the input,
I expect validation error message "interactionId cannot be empty" but the validation passes through which i guess could be due to the fact that interactionId has a default value of 0.

Can someone pls. help to enforce this validation on the 'long' parameter when its not given in input?

with @NotEmpty for the customerId param, its working as expected. Using @NotEmpty for the long param "interactionId" is throwing a different error that @notempty cannot be used for long.

```
public class Input {

@NotEmpty(message = "customerId cannot be empty")
private String customerId;

@Valid
@NotNull(message = "interactionId cannot be empty")
private long interactionId;
 // setters and getters

}
```

my controller class:
    @RestController
public class Controller {

```
@PostMapping(value="/detailed-customer-transaction", produces = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> detailTransactions(@Valid @RequestBody Input 
params)
{
    return new ResponseEntity<>(Dao.detailTransactions(params), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Above issues is resolved after changing to Long instead of long.

**Query #2**
I need another help. I have a String input param which takes date-time format in below format. Given its a string parameter, how can i validate for the pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

long should be Long, because long is a primary type in java, not an object, so Long is an object that can be checked whether it is null

Comment: My bad!...so silly of me. I over-looked. That worked. Thanks @clevertension.

Comment: Hi @clevertension Can you pls. help me with query #2?

Comment: you can refer to this https://riptutorial.com/spring-mvc/example/23897/spring-mvc-form-validation-with-bean-validation-api

Comment: add @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")

Comment: I tried it but doesnt throw any validation error when i input a different format. Given my api input is JSON and date input will be given as a string, I wanted to keep the input datatype as well to String and enforce this validation.

Comment: ok, that you should implement a custom validator, please refer this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator